# How to bind qooxdoo property to a widget?

Tags: javascript, qooxdoo

I'm absolutly new with Qooxdoo.

I want to bind a property to a label, as in the code below, but that does't work :(

```
qx.Class.define("xxx.view.XxxView",
{
  extend : qx.ui.container.Composite,

  properties : {
    CaseID : {
      check : 'String',
      event : 'changeCaseID',
      init  : '000000000'
    }
  },

  members : {
    _CaseIDLabel : null
  },

  construct : function()
  {
    this._CaseIDLabel = new qx.ui.basic.Label("initial");
    this.CaseID.bind('changeCaseID', this._CaseIDLabel, 'value');
  }
}
```

thx 4 hints

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access the property directly. You have to use geters and setters to access it's value. You could instead bind the whole property. The binding system is smart enough to detect the event emitted, extract the property's value and apply it to the target.

Here is a working code

```js
    qx.Class.define("xxx.view.XxxView", {
  extend : qx.ui.container.Composite,

 construct : function() {
   this.base(arguments);
    this._CaseIDLabel = new qx.ui.basic.Label("initial");

    // containers need a layout
    this.setLayout(new qx.ui.layout.Canvas());
    this.add(this._CaseIDLabel);

    // notice here we are binding this object's property
    this.bind('CaseID', this._CaseIDLabel, 'value');
  },

  properties : {
    CaseID : {
      check : 'String',
      event : "changeCaseID",
      init  : '000000000'
    }
  },

  members : {
    _CaseIDLabel : null
  },
});
```

here is the playground example
https:// tinyurl.com/rt5v8zx

Answer (score 1):

Here's another example doing things a little bit differently. See the embedded comments.

```
qx.Class.define("xxx.view.XxxView",
{
  extend : qx.ui.container.Composite,

  properties : {
    CaseID : {
      check : 'String',
      event : "changeCaseID",
      init  : '000000000'
    }
  },

  members : {
    _CaseIDLabel : null
  },

  construct : function()
  {
    // We need to call the superclass constructor.
    // In this case, we also provide a layout for this container.
    this.base(arguments, new qx.ui.layout.VBox());

    // Here we instantiate a Label with initial text, but that text
    // will be immediately overwritten so we'll never see it
    this._CaseIDLabel = new qx.ui.basic.Label("initial");
    this.add(this._CaseIDLabel);

    // We can bind to our own property, as done here. Note, though,
    // that this doesn't use the being-initialized value in the property
    // without explicit instruction... so we then force-initialize that
    // property.
    this.bind('changeCaseID', this._CaseIDLabel, 'value');
    this.initCaseID();
  }
});

// Instantiate one of these xxxView objects, and place it on the page
var xxxView = new xxx.view.XxxView();
this.getRoot().add(xxxView, { left : 10, top : 200 } );

// Show how the property value can change later, and update the label
setTimeout(
  function()
  {
    xxxView.setCaseID('Hello world!');    
  },
  2000);
```

This can be seen running in the playground: http:// tinyurl.com/vml8bru